# Ignore child elements when selecting elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery

here is my HTML:

```
<div class="foo">
    <span class="ignore_this">IGNORE THIS TEXT</span>
    SELECT THIS
</div>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to select all the stuff inside `foo`, but not the stuff inside `ignore_this`:

```
$("div.foo:not(span.ignore_this)").text()
```

but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selector `div.foo:not(span.ignore_this)` is saying "match every `div.foo` that isn't a `span.ignore_this`" which is only going to select one element: `div.foo`.  If you restructured your html like this:

```
<div class="foo">
    <span class="ignore_this">IGNORE THIS TEXT</span>
    <span>SELECT THIS</span>
</div>
```

Then you could call:

```
$('div.foo span:not(.ignore_this)').text();
```

Which matches all `span` elements which are descendants of a `div.foo` that are not `.ignore_this`.

If you don't have the luxury of reformatting the html, then you could accomplish what you want with extra processor cycles:

```
var clone = $('div.foo').clone();
$('span.ignore_this', clone).remove();
var text = clone.text();
```