# jQuery load only certain div content, not parent divs

Tags: jquery, html, load

```
<div id="value">
 10.00

  <div id="text">hello!</div>
</div>



<script>
setInterval(function(){
    $("#value").load("value.php #value");
}, 5000);
</script>
```

This is my content of my file.

How do i prevent script loading `<div id="text">` too?

Comment: Maybe that can help? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507858/ignore-child-elements-when-selecting-elements-in-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use load and then using load's callback, simply remove the div you don't need. Note that you should try to avoid using repeat IDs as it looks like the div you're loading into has an ID of value and the file you're loading from also has an Id of value.

```
$('#value').load("value.php #value", function () {
    $('#text').remove();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/L4ZRD/)** (note that this example uses jsFiddle's AJAX echo API to simulate the call).

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent that because `load` gets whole file.

You can use `ajax` function instead, load the data, manipulate the string then put it into the div.

Or remove the child element after the load is complete:

```
<script>
setInterval(function(){
    $("#value").load(
         "value.php", 
         function() {
            $('#text').remove();
         }
    );
}, 5000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understood your question, you want to load content from `#value` div from `value.php` page and you don't want this `<div id="text">`:

```
setInterval(function(){
    var content = $("<span id='content'/>").load("value.php #value");
    $('#value').html(content);
}, 5000);
```